# Google Elevation API - uphill and downhill values

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I open Google Maps in a browser, and I search for a cycling path from point X to point Y, the browser shows me the path, and also shows information about how many meters uphill I will need to cycle, and how many meters downhill.

I've been trying to fetch such information via the Elevation API, but I don't know how Google Maps is making those calculations. What I do is:

1) First I call DirectionService to get a cycling path between points X and Y.

2) Then I get the overview_path from the returned route.

3) Then call the ElevationService passing all the points returned by the decoded overview_path.

4) Finally I try to calculate the uphill and downhill values in meters... So I iterate through all the elevation results which ElevationService returns, if the next elevation result is bigger than the previous one, then I increase my uphill counter with the difference (and if it is smaller then the previous one, then I increase my downhill counter with the difference).

And after that I end up with a value different from the Google Maps uphill and downhill... Can you suggest me how should I proceed to get the same uphill and downhill as Google Maps shows in the browser?

Some interesting notes:

1) Using the overview_path I usually get bigger values for uphill and downhill than what Google Maps shows. This is probably because I'm "probing" the path with a higher density.

2) However when I have passed the "steps" points (returned by DirectionService) into the ElevationService, then I get smaller values. This is probably because I'm "probing" the path with a lower density.

A sample code that shows what I do you can find below. The code is C# (.NET 3.5), I'm using GoogleMapsApi wrapper for .NET (https://github.com/maximn/google-maps/):

...

```
ElevationRequest request = new ElevationRequest()
{
    Locations = listOfPoints // a list of points retrieved from the overview_path
    ApiKey = apiKey
};

ElevationResponse response = GoogleMaps.Elevation.Query(request);
List<double> allElevations = new List<double>();        
foreach (var r in response.Results)
{
    allElevations.Add(r.Elevation);
}

double upHill = 0;
double downHill = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < allElevations.Count; i++)
{
    double thisElevation = allElevations[i];
    double previousElevation = allElevations[i - 1];
    if (thisElevation > previousElevation)
    {
        upHill += thisElevation - previousElevation; // Moving up the hill... 
    }
    else if (thisElevation < previousElevation)
    {
        downHill += previousElevation - thisElevation; // Moving down the hill... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged both [[google-maps-api-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3)] and (the deprecated and turned off) [[google-maps-api-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2)]? What does your code look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the behavior you are describing.

Comment: The google-maps-api-2 tag was removed. Please see a code example in the edited question. Any suggestions would be appreciated.